# Is this same origin policy?

Tags: ajax, same-origin-policy

I'm setting my AJAX request URL to `http://www.domain.com` which is the current domain that the javascript file itself is under. But if I enter with `http://domain.com` it'll never send request. I know this is somehow a same origin policy but the thing is I've never faced this problem until now. BTW, I'm rewriting all requests to my `index.php`, could it be something related? And could be the host itself that is doing this because on my localhost everything is fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; the same-origin policy will prevent that.

You should use domain-relative URLs (`/a/b/c...`), which will just use the current domain.

Comment: You mean `/admin/panel` for example instead of `http://www.domain.com/admin/panel`?